# Fourier transform with second order differentials

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How do I start this question:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = yx$$ for a function $y(x)$ which tends to zero as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Show that transform of $\hat{y}(k)$ of $y(x)$ satisfies the first order differential equation: 
$$\frac{d\hat{y}}{dk} = ik^2 \hat{y}$$

Comment: Do you know an expression for the frequency derivative of the fourier transform?

Comment: No, i don't. Sorry

Comment: Try and take the derivative of $\hat{y}(\omega) = \mathcal{F}(y)(\omega)$ with respect to $\omega$ by passing the derivative inside the integral.

Comment: Where does the $(\omega)$  comes from ?

Comment: In your case it's just $k$. Try and take the derivative by exchanging it with the integral.

Comment: I don't get what i have to do. How do i take the derivative by exchanging it with the integral ? I am sorry.

Comment: Notice that $\partial_\omega \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x) \partial_\omega e^{-i \omega x} dx$ because the integral does not depend on $\omega$, and then calculate the inside of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$\partial_\omega \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x) \partial_\omega e^{-i \omega x} dx$$ because the integral does not depend on $\omega$, and then calculate the inside of the integral.